# Azure PowerShell Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup invalid Address prefix

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

While trying to add NSG Rule, I am getting below error:

```
 Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName MYRG -Name MYNSG | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name AllowSyslog-Outbound -Access Allow -Protocol * -Direction Outbound -Priority 3001 -SourceAddressPrefix 10.200.32.36 -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix "10.201.0.5,10.201.2.4" -DestinationPortRange (514, 6514) | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
```

Throws error:

```
Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup: Security rule /subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/MYRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/MYNSG/securityRules/AllowSyslog-Outbound has invalid Address prefix. Value provided: 10.201.0.5,10.201.2.4
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
ErrorCode: SecurityRuleInvalidAddressPrefix
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for using multiple IP address in `Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig` is as below:

```
Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName MYRG -Name MYNSG `
| Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
-Name AllowSyslog-Outbound -Access Allow -Protocol * `
-Direction Outbound -Priority 3001 `
-SourceAddressPrefix 10.200.32.36 `
-SourcePortRange * `
-DestinationAddressPrefix ("10.201.0.5", "10.201.2.4") `
-DestinationPortRange (514, 6514) `
| Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
```